# load output on tkinter flickring

Tags: python, tkinter

I want to display load cell output on tkinter window as a label but label fluctuates sometimes. Is there a way to make it stable? I am using [this](https://github.com/endail/hx711) for interfacing loadcell with pi.

[Video link](https://youtu.be/HhuoPWeGxzY) to see flickering weight label.

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk

from HX711 import *
global w
global hx

hx = SimpleHX711(27, 17, 198227, 114496)
def core():   
global w

global hx
hx.setUnit(Mass.Unit.KG)
hx.zero()

while True:
    
    m = float(hx.weight(1))
    x = abs(m)
    w = float('{:.1f}'.format(x))
    
    weight = Label(root,text=w,font = ('', 100))
    weight.place(x=300,y=200)
    

    weight.forget()
    weight.update()

root = Tk()
root.geometry("800x500")
root.title("Weight scale")
sbtn = Button(root, text=' End  ', font=('', 40), pady=40)
sbtn.place(x=325, y=0)
#t1 = threading.Thread(target=core)
#t1.start()
root.after(10,core)

root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you keep creating new widgets on top of old widgets. The proper way to do it is to create the widget once, and then just change the text.

Move the creation of the label outside of the loop, and then use the `configure` method to update the text (eg: `weight.configure(text=w)`)